# i need a tampermonkey select a specify size command

Tags: html, attributes, tampermonkey

Can I have the *tampermonkey* with *jquery* command for select a specify size? I have this situation:

```
<select name="group_1" id="group_1" class="attribute_select" onchange="findCombination();getProductAttribute();$('#wrapResetImages').show('slow');;">
  <option title="44" value="19">44</option>
  <option title="45" value="21">45</option>
  <option title="46" value="23">46</option>
</select>
```

[image: [enter image description here]]

I used this command but it select size but doesn't work finally:

```
var size = "46";

var sliceright = size.length;

function setSelectedIndex (s, v) {
  for ( var i = 0; i < s.options.length; i++ ) {
    if ( s.options[i].text.slice(0,sliceright) == v ) {
      s.options[i].selected = true;
      return;
    }
  }
}
setSelectedIndex (document.getElementById('group_1'),size);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that I understand correctly your question, but If you want a *JQuery* selector to select a `<option>` by text instead of by `value` attribute you can try with:

```js
var text = '46';

// select the element by id which has an <option> an contains 
// the desired text. Then set the selected attribute
$('#group_1 option:contains("' + text + '")').attr('selected', 'selected');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="group_1" id="group_1" class="attribute_select">
  <option title="44" value="19">44</option>
  <option title="45" value="21">45</option>
  <option title="46" value="23">46</option>
</select>
```

**UPDATE:**

After check out your example seems that in your web it's necessary to invoke `click`  event after select an `<option>`. Also since all the `<select>` has a different `id` attribute but the same `class`, maybe it's more convenient use this as selector instead of the `id`. In short you can try with:

```
var text = '46';
$('.attribute_select option:contains("' + text + '")').attr('selected', 'selected').click();
```

Comment: hi, thanks for the answer. The problem is that the script works and select the true size, but when i go the cart for the payment there is an other size. i give you the link: http://www.slamjamsocialism.com/footwear/15570-gel-lyte-v-maldives-pack-sneakers.html

Comment: https://twitter.com/curla92/status/710112389845356544 there you can check the error. thanks

Comment: @FrancescoCurletti I update my answer, take a look on it `:)`